# Issues with pChart outputting image. Whats wrong?

Tags: php, pchart

I'm having an issue displaying the 3DPie example pChart in my php page, no matter what the output (Stroke(),autoOutput(),render()) it doesn't render to the browser, but the examples work in the examples folder.

My question is: why won't it render to browser? How do I fix it? (its not the includes, they worked for the basic syntax tutorial)

```
include("code libraries/pChart2.1.3/class/pDraw.class.php");
include("code libraries/pChart2.1.3/class/pImage.class.php");
include("code libraries/pChart2.1.3/class/pData.class.php");

 /* Create and populate the pData object */
 $MyData = new pData();   
 $MyData->addPoints(array(50,2,3,4,7,10,25,48,41,10),"ScoreA");  
 $MyData->setSerieDescription("ScoreA","Application A");

 /* Define the absissa serie */
 $MyData->addPoints(array("A0","B1","C2","D3","E4","F5","G6","H7","I8","J9"),"Labels");
 $MyData->setAbscissa("Labels");

 /* Create the pChart object */
 $myPicture = new pImage(300,260,$MyData);

 /* Draw a solid background */
 $Settings = array("R"=>170, "G"=>183, "B"=>87, "Dash"=>1, "DashR"=>190, "DashG"=>203, "DashB"=>107);
 $myPicture->drawFilledRectangle(0,0,300,300,$Settings);

 /* Overlay with a gradient */
 $Settings = array("StartR"=>219, "StartG"=>231, "StartB"=>139, "EndR"=>1, "EndG"=>138, "EndB"=>68, "Alpha"=>50);
 $myPicture->drawGradientArea(0,0,300,260,DIRECTION_VERTICAL,$Settings);
 $myPicture->drawGradientArea(0,0,300,20,DIRECTION_VERTICAL,array("StartR"=>0,"StartG"=>0,"StartB"=>0,"EndR"=>50,"EndG"=>50,"EndB"=>50,"Alpha"=>100));

 /* Add a border to the picture */
 $myPicture->drawRectangle(0,0,299,259,array("R"=>0,"G"=>0,"B"=>0));

 /* Write the picture title */ 
 $myPicture->setFontProperties(array("FontName"=>"code libraries/pChart2.1.3/fonts/Silkscreen.ttf","FontSize"=>6));
 $myPicture->drawText(10,13,"pPie - Draw 2D pie charts",array("R"=>255,"G"=>255,"B"=>255));

 /* Set the default font properties */ 
 $myPicture->setFontProperties(array("FontName"=>"code libraries/pChart2.1.3/fonts/Forgotte.ttf","FontSize"=>10,"R"=>80,"G"=>80,"B"=>80));

 /* Create the pPie object */ 
 $PieChart = new pPie($myPicture,$MyData);

 /* Draw an AA pie chart */ 
 $PieChart->draw3DPie(160,140,array("Radius"=>70,"DrawLabels"=>TRUE,"LabelStacked"=>TRUE,"Border"=>TRUE));

 /* Write the legend box */ 
 $myPicture->setShadow(FALSE);
 $PieChart->drawPieLegend(15,40,array("Alpha"=>20));

 /* Render the picture (choose the best way) */
 $myPicture->autoOutput("vgraph.png");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Possible Errors

A. You did not include `pPie.class.php` in your script

B. Possible wrong path

C. Possible Wrong Font location

### Try

```
require("lib/pchart/class/pData.class.php");
require("lib/pchart/class/pDraw.class.php");
require("lib/pchart/class/pImage.class.php");
require("lib/pchart/class/pPie.class.php");


$font1 = "lib/pchart/fonts/pf_arma_five.ttf" ;
$font2 = "lib/pchart/fonts/pf_arma_five.ttf" ;

 $MyData = new pData();   
 $MyData->addPoints(array(50,2,3,4,7,10,25,48,41,10),"ScoreA");  
 $MyData->setSerieDescription("ScoreA","Application A");

 /* Define the absissa serie */
 $MyData->addPoints(array("A0","B1","C2","D3","E4","F5","G6","H7","I8","J9"),"Labels");
 $MyData->setAbscissa("Labels");

 /* Create the pChart object */
 $myPicture = new pImage(300,260,$MyData);

 /* Draw a solid background */
 $Settings = array("R"=>170, "G"=>183, "B"=>87, "Dash"=>1, "DashR"=>190, "DashG"=>203, "DashB"=>107);
 $myPicture->drawFilledRectangle(0,0,300,300,$Settings);

 /* Overlay with a gradient */
 $Settings = array("StartR"=>219, "StartG"=>231, "StartB"=>139, "EndR"=>1, "EndG"=>138, "EndB"=>68, "Alpha"=>50);
 $myPicture->drawGradientArea(0,0,300,260,DIRECTION_VERTICAL,$Settings);
 $myPicture->drawGradientArea(0,0,300,20,DIRECTION_VERTICAL,array("StartR"=>0,"StartG"=>0,"StartB"=>0,"EndR"=>50,"EndG"=>50,"EndB"=>50,"Alpha"=>100));

 /* Add a border to the picture */
 $myPicture->drawRectangle(0,0,299,259,array("R"=>0,"G"=>0,"B"=>0));

 /* Write the picture title */ 
 $myPicture->setFontProperties(array("FontName"=>$font1,"FontSize"=>6));
 $myPicture->drawText(10,13,"pPie - Draw 2D pie charts",array("R"=>255,"G"=>255,"B"=>255));

 /* Set the default font properties */ 
 $myPicture->setFontProperties(array("FontName"=>$font2,"FontSize"=>10,"R"=>80,"G"=>80,"B"=>80));

 /* Create the pPie object */ 
 $PieChart = new pPie($myPicture,$MyData);

 /* Draw an AA pie chart */ 
 $PieChart->draw3DPie(160,140,array("Radius"=>70,"DrawLabels"=>TRUE,"LabelStacked"=>TRUE,"Border"=>TRUE));

 /* Write the legend box */ 
 $myPicture->setShadow(FALSE);
 $PieChart->drawPieLegend(15,40,array("Alpha"=>20));

 /* Render the picture (choose the best way) */
 $myPicture->autoOutput("vgraph.png");
```

### Result

[image: Final Output]

Comment: It took so long for an answer I ended up fixing this myself, but thanks!

Comment: Wow ... people usually run form difficult answers .. to bad i was not able to help you earlier enough ... +1  for accepting even after it has been resolved

Comment: Should help anyone else having the same issue in the future. And not only did I get that working, I have a bar graph pulling data from comma delimited text files and displaying it.